# YAWS crash uploading 7 MB file

Tags: erlang, yaws

I'm using a Raspberry like board with YAWS 2.0.4 and Erlang 19.

I wrote two webpages to upload a file and save it on the server: with "larger" file (I mean, ~7MB) the server crashes, with smaller file all works fine.

I already tried to use the example code found in the YAWS site and another one with the *temp_file* and *binary* options, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any log files? or crash dump?

Comment: The amount of storage remaining on your SD card is less then 7MB?

Comment: The node has a load peak and the OOM kills it. I'm using 8GB emmc, isn't a free space problem.

Answer (score 2):

After spending much time, I've found the problem: the *partial_post_size* parameter in the YAWS configuration was too much high.

I've changed it, near the default value (10240) and all works fine.